# Pop!_OS - Ethernet stopped working and WiFi not working (dmesg errors included)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wifi, pop-os

The machine I am running has two operating systems on their own drives (Windows 10 and Pop!_OS 21.10) I installed Pop!_OS about a week ago and everything was working normally until recently. One day Ethernet stopped working and WiFi has never worked for me. Any assistance in getting both/either of these working again would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION:**

> ProtonVPN has 3 Kill Switch options. Off, On, and Permanent. It was switched to Permanent which blocks all traffic unless the VPN was connected, even if the ProtonVPN application is not running. This also explains why it worked fine for a week or so and must have stopped working after I installed ProtonVPN.

I'm wondering if this has to do with the DHCP lease or some sort of conflict where the router is confused that two different operating systems are using the same hardware (at different times).

`lspci` tells me my ethernet controller is:

> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev16).

If it helps my motherboard is a Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. Z390 UD

Looking through posts here with similar problems I have tried/checked the following:

- Rebooted my router.
- Windows Fast Boot is disabled (it has been the whole time but I double checked).
- Tried booting with the Ethernet cable disconnected then plugging it in once it was booted.
- Ethernet works fine when I boot into Windows 10.

Looking through the output of dmesg for errors that may be related I see the following:

```
bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: No SPROM available
```

Additionally, I am unable to use my WiFi: Broadcom Inc BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] rev 03

In the output from `dmesg` I see the following:

```
b43-phy0: Broadcom 4352 WLAN found (core revision 42)
b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)
b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -95
Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
```

I don't think these are related but other errors I noticed:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-2: device not accepting address 5, error -71
usb 1-2: device not accepting address 6, error -71
usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 1-4: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
usb 1-4: 4:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x2
```

Output from `lspci -v -s 05:00.0`

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at 53604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 53600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

I have installed `ethtool` via USB.

The output for `sudo ethtool enp5s0` is:

```
Settings for enp5s0:
Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                     1000baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
master-slave cfg: preferred slave
master-slave status: master
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: external
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Link detected: yes
```

Output of `ip address show dev enp5s0`

```
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:78:5c:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft 86373sec preferred_lft 86373sec
    inet6 fe80::3437:55d6:7fd8:bc93/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Since it is showing a network IP I looked at the attached devices on the router and I see the following assigned IPs:

- POP-OS 192.168.1.28 5G WiFi
- POP-OS 192.168.1.26 5G WiFi
- POP-OS 192.168.1.20 5G WiFi
- POP-OS 192.168.1.2 ETH
- POP-OS 192.168.1.25 2.4G WiFi

Output from `ip route`

```
default via 100.85.0.1 dev pvpnksintrf0 proto static metric 98 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
100.85.0.0/24 dev pvpnksintrf0 proto kernel scope link src 100.85.0.1 metric 98 
169.254.0.0/16 dev pvpnksintrf0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.25 metric 100
```

Output from `resolvectl`

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp5s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 4 (pvpnksintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.
```

Comment: The bcma messages likely belong to the broadcom wifi actually. There are probably other messages that belong to the ethernet card. It would be nice to know which driver is used. Could you post output of `lspci -v -s aa:bb.c` with aa:bb.c the first number that you see from `lspci | grep -i ethernet`. Also, do you have `ethtool` installed?

Comment: @user7138814 - I don't have ethtool installed.
The output reads:
`05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at 53604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 53600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169`

Comment: @user7138814 I also updated the original post with the information you requested.

Comment: @user7138814 I was able to install ethtool via USB

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional output, it shows that the hardware is working. Next you could check if you get an ip address. You could look at `ip address show dev enp5s0`. For a working connection there should be a line starting with `inet` that contains an ip address. If there's no ip address you can search through the logs (`dmesg` and `journalctl`) looking for example for enp5s0, dhclient, dhcp, DHCP.

Comment: @user7138814 Updated original with output of `ip address show dev enp5s0`

Comment: Ok, so far so good. What about `ip route` and `resolvectl` ?

Comment: @user7138814 Updated with outputs from `ip route` and `resolvectl`
Strangely I had an internet connection for about 15-30 min on it today after I updated my router. It makes be think it has to do with the DHCP lease or some sort of conflict where the router is confused that two different operating systems are on the same hardware. I have Pop!_OS on it's own SSD and Windows 10 on another drive.

Comment: My guess is the issue is with ProtonVPN. If you search the net for `pvpnksintrf0` there are lots of other similar cases, i.e. working local network but no internet access. The `ip route` output shows that traffic to the internet is sent to a gateway 100.85.0.1, which is likely not functioning properly. The gateway of the local network is 192.168.1.1 but this has a higher metric so a lower priority.

Comment: @user7138814 Oh my god you're right. ProtonVPN has 3 Kill Switch options. Off, On, and Permanent. It was switched to Permanent which blocks all traffic unless the VPN was connected, even if the ProtonVPN application is not running. This also explains why it worked fine for a week or so and must have stopped working after I installed ProtonVPN.

Comment: Good to hear that it's sorted now. It's understandable that such a thing happens, if you reboot you expect the machine to go to a known working state. If not then on Linux it's often some software update that's messing with the devices..

Comment: Thank you @user7138814 for all your help. Not only were you able to help identify the problem but you taught me about debugging network issues.